# How to draw an updating line

Tags: c#, drawing, line

My goal is very simple. Imagine opening MSPaint, clicking the line tool, holding mouse down, and dragging it around. It anchors the starting coordinates where you clicked mouse down and constantly draws and redraws a line to your current position.

Except me trying to do this in C# isn't working as well as I would hope.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    endingPoint = GetMouseCoords();
    DrawLine(startingPoint, endingPoint);
}

private void DrawLine(Point startingCoords, Point endingCoords)
{
    IntPtr desktop = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
    Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktop))
    {
        g.DrawLine(pen, startingCoords.X, startingCoords.Y, endingCoords.X, endingCoords.Y);
        g.Dispose();
    }
    ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktop);
}
```

Using it this way, I only get the line drawn once. However, if I move the DrawLine() to a more static event like MouseUp, it will draw it, then disappear after about a quarter of a second.

**What would be the best way to accomplish my goal here?**

I would think that whatever event is being used to make the line disappear is what I would want to attach the drawing of the line to in the first place.

Comment: So are you trying to draw onto the Desktop? Why??

Answer (score 2):

You need to have **two** drawing calls:

- One for the **non-persistent line** that follows the cursor in the `MouseMove` using `someControls.CreateGraphics`
- the other for the **persisting** line, triggered in the `MouseUp`, where

  - you store the coordinates and
  - call `Invalidate` on your canvas control and
  - draw in the `Paint` event of your canvas  using its `e.Graphics` object.

Here is a minimal example code:

```
List<Point> allPoints = new List<Point>();
Point mDown = Point.Empty;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = e.Location;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    allPoints.Add(e.Location);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        using (Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
            G.DrawLine(Pens.Red, mDown, e.Location);
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (allPoints.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Black, allPoints.ToArray());
}
```

Note that this uses a `PictureBox` as the canvas control. It is the control meant for this kind of interaction. Your code seems to draw onto the desktop, which doesn't belong to you. Drawing onto it in a persistent manner is not anything like what you would do with the/any Paint application.

Also note that my example stores a list of points and draws them as one **non-closed Polyline**. To draw them **closed** exchange `DrawLines` for `DrawPolygon`! To draw **several** such polylines or polygons you need to..

- ..decide on the user interface for it, maybe **add** segment points only while the **control-key** is pressed and **otherwise** finish the current polyline
- store the points in a `List<List, Point>>`

---

Also note that this is one of the **rare** examples where using `control.CreateGraphics` is called for, as you actually do **want a non-persistent** drawing while the user moves the mouse.

In **most other cases** the Winforms graphics basic rule #1 applies:

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: Thank you. Your solution isn't quite what I was looking for, but is enough to point me in the right direction. I was only drawing to the desktop because I didn't know of a better way. I have since added a pictureBox to the maximized but transparent form that layers above the desktop.