# How to change the background color in a rectangle in a winforms grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am building a graph using the following code.  I need to be able to change the color of any given rectangle by clicking on it with the mouse.  I am, so far, unable to find a way to accomplish this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
    int number;
    public List<Rectangle> listRec = new List<Rectangle>();
    Graphics g;

    public CrochetPtrnDesign()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            listRec.Clear();
            rect.Size = new Size((pnlDesign.Width - 1) / number, (pnlDesign.Height - 1) / number);
            for (int x = 0; x < number; x++)
            {
                rect.X = x * rect.Width;
                for (int y = 0; y < number; y++)
                {
                    rect.Y = y * rect.Height;
                    listRec.Add(rect);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number...");
        }
        foreach (Rectangle rec in listRec)
        {
            g = pnlDesign.CreateGraphics();
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
            g.DrawRectangle(p, rec);
        }
    }
```

Comment: _g = pnlDesign.CreateGraphics();_ NEVER use control.CreateGraphics() unless you actually want to result to be non-persistent!!! You __need__ to do all drawing in the Paint event, using data you store at class level. Wheneve these data change trigger the Paint event by doing pnlDesign.Invalidate and let it draw __everything__ from scratch agian.

Comment: 1) Why do you always re-create the Rectangle list? It needs to be created whenever the sizes chenge, not on each click. 2) What colors do the rectangles have before clicking them?

Comment: What the code supposed to do? If you want to change color of rectangle by click, you need a simple hit-test on your rectangles using `Rectangle.Contains(Point)`.

Comment: I have a form that asks the user what size grid they want.  Example, if they type 30, they get a grid of 30 x 30 inside a panel of set dimensions 500 x 500.  The result is a grid that is always the same size, but the number of grid lines changes depending on user input.  The point of the application is to simplify some of my wifes crochet pattern design.  She can select a color, fill in the cells that she wants to be that color and then pick the next color until the design is complete.  After that, to be able to print a written guide that she can carry around with her.  Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish this.  Here is the code that I am using now.  I will still have to build the color selection tool, but that is going to be the easy part, I think.
All of your suggestions helped lead me to the solution.  I thank you all.

```
private void pnlDesign_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point point = pnlDesign.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    SolidBrush blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);

    int listCount = 0;
    for (listCount = 0; listCount < number * number; listCount++)
    {
        if (listRec[listCount].Contains(point))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(blueBrush, listRec[listCount]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this better than my answer?

Comment: I was never able to figure out how to get the "listRec.Where" to work.  Your answer did point me in the direction of the "Contains" which is what makes all this possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the issue of selecting the color, but you might be able to start by adding this:

```
private void pnlDesign_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, listRec.Where(r => r.Contains(new Point { X = e.X, Y = e.Y })).First());
    }    
}
```

EDIT:

Updated to uses Reza's recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

Try the FillRectangle method if you need to fill the rectangle with color.

If you need to change the color of just the borders you will need to ReRender it by calling the following code again with a different color:

```
g = pnlDesign.CreateGraphics();
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
g.DrawRectangle(p, rec);
```

Comment: On the initial draw, I need the rectangle fill to be a default color.  After that, I need to select a color elsewhere in the application, and then I need every rectangle I click on to fill with that new color... select a new color again, click on more different rectangles, so on and so on.  I do not need to change the border colors at any point.  Thank you.

Comment: _g = pnlDesign.CreateGraphics();_ NEVER use control.CreateGraphics() unless you actually want to result to be non-persistent!!!

Comment: Thank you, TaW.  If there is a better way to build this grid, I am open to suggestions... Annd very grateful.

Comment: @SeanConnelly Actually I found almost the exact same thing on another StackOverflow question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414334/how-to-draw-an-updating-line

Comment: @TaW Thank you. You are right g.CreateGraphics is non-perstent and would mean you have to manage the redrawing of everything yourself which is mayor overkill.

Comment: @ZoranBogdanov  Sorry, but, no.  That article has nothing to do with what I am trying to accomplish.  The lines are already established and not moving or changing color.  I need to fill the area or background of a rectangle of my choosing out of many.  The core of the issue is how do I identify the exact rectangle that I clicked in? (I think...)