# update position of circle on pictureBox

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, picturebox

I am using a pictureBox to move 2 linear stages; when the mouseDown event triggers, the pictureBox coordinates are remapped to match the maximum travel length of the axis, and then sent to them to perform the movement.

To improve this feature i have added a tiny dot on this image to track the current position of the mouse during the mouseDown event.
the dot must update its positition everytime the mouse moves; in order to do so i have used gfx.Clear(Color.White); to delete the previous and draw the new one.
Problem is that to understand the correct positioning of the axis the pictureBox should show a photo of the axis; but calling the gfx.Clear(Color) clears the image and leaves me with a white background.

is there a way to update the dot position without calling the gfx.Clear (in order to keep the image?)

```
if (e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
            {
                {
                    this.gridImage.Refresh();
                    convertedX = (e.X * 100) / gridImage.Size.Width;
                    convertedY = (e.Y * 100) / gridImage.Size.Height;
                    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(this.gridImage.Image))
                    {
                        circle_bounds.X = e.X;
                        circle_bounds.Y = e.Y;
                        gfx.Clear(Color.White);

                        gfx.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, this.circle_bounds);


                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("(X,Y): " + convertedX.ToString() + " " + convertedY.ToString());
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                    //moveAbs(port1, "1", convertedX.ToString());
                    //moveAbs(port2, "1", convertedY.ToString());
                    initialXText.Text = convertedX.ToString();
                    initialYText.Text = convertedY.ToString();

                }
            }
```

Comment: You should draw the circle onto the surface of the Pbox. Use `using (Graphics gfx = gridImage.CreateGraphics)` for this; throw in a Refresh()!. The result will not persist, but that is not what you want, right? For persistent drawing use the Paint event and its e.Graphics object and gridImage.Invalidate to trigger the Paint.. - Are you sure about the Sleep in a MouseMove??? Sounds awfully choppy! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414334/how-to-draw-an-updating-line/38419518?s=24|0.0642#38419518) for an updating line example!

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks!

Comment: Do note:  `Graphics gfx = gridImage.CreateGraphics()` usually is a serious mistake as the data are __not persistent__, i.e. are gone e.g. after minimizing the form. Using it here is a rare __exception__ to the rules!

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is using the `PictureBox.Paint` event to draw the point that must follow the mouse move. First I declare a `Point`to store the mouse position any time it moves:

```
Point mousePosition;
```

Then, in the `PictureBox.MouseMove` event handler, I would store this location and invalidate the `PictureBox`:

```
private void gridImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mousePosition = e.Location;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Finally, in the `PictureBox.Paint` i just draw a circle using the mouse position:

```
private void gridImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(mousePosition, new Size(5,5)));
}
```

Hope this leads you in the right direction