# How can I draw in C# on all side of Form?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, draw

I can't draw in this code without depending on Property ( Normal, Mixsemize, Minimize)

So how can I draw when I put on Property Normal on All the form not just on border Normal you can found a picture that I amended below to explain what I want. I tried a lot to fix this problem but I can't find the solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DrawC
{
    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        int x = -1;
        int y = -1;
        bool movieng = false;
        Pen pen;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None ;
            pen =new Pen (Color .Black ,5);
            pen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round   ;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox p = (PictureBox)sender;
            pen.Color = p.BackColor;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            movieng = true;
            x = e.X;
            y = e.Y;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            movieng = false;
            x = -1;
            y = -1;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (movieng && x != -1 && y != -1)
            {
                g.DrawLine(pen, new Point(x, y), e.Location);
                x = e.X;
                y = e.Y;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            this.TopMost = true;
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        } 
    }
}
```

I need to fix this code to draw without deoed Property ( Normal, Mixsemize,  Minimize).

Here is a screenshot of my current output:
[image]

Comment: _g = this.CreateGraphics();_ - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. - Also: Do try to fix your spelling!

Comment: Sorry man, I am weak  in English
I will try and give you news

Comment: Sure; come back if you run into more issues. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve, though. What is the PictureBox for? Drawing onto it?? You will need to __collect__ all points into a List<Point> and can then draw all in the Paint event (`e.Graphics.DrawLines(yourPen, yourList.ToArray());`) - Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38414334/how-to-draw-an-updating-line/38419518#38419518) that shows how to combine both non-persistent and persistent drawing to do freehand drawing; it is a little involved, but worth looking at..

Comment: but man how can i draw on Bitmap without use a control ? if i but it in picturebox it is will convert to control don't you think that

Comment: Well I didn't suggest to draw into a Bitmap. It is most useful if you want to keep the result. For live drawing better draw onto a control; drawing onto a PictureBox is the recommended way. Simply code its Paint event as you can see in the example.. Note that you can only see as much as the size of that control..

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer may brother

Comment: Did you make any progress on this Raho?

Comment: you can find my program in this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOxI54VoECg  When I draw in the program I can not draw on full screen look to this picture to undrstod what i men  https://e.top4top.net/p_1188phn821.png you can use the program for more info